# Управление процессом из winapi

Tags: c, winapi, процесс

Нужно как-то из main управлять другим процессом. Читал, что есть CreateProcess, но инфы очень мало и непонятно. Может кто знает какой функцией говорить процессу: создай дерево, вставь туды элемент 11, удали элемент 14 и т.д. и т.п.

Тут важно понимать, что использование потоков - не прокатит!

(Спасибо, Sergey Gornostaev, очень помог, но как оказалось - нужно через процессы. НО! за знания отдельное огромное спасибо, хоть разобрался с потоками.)

Comment: Выяснил, что нужно копать в сторону PostMessage и SendMessage

Comment: Можете дать пример с использованием этих функций?
Спасибо!

Comment: Вам лучше начать с какой-нибудь книжки - Петцольд + Рихтер будут отличным вариантом. Ответить вам в двух словах невозможно, а пересказ Рихтера далеко выходит за формат stackoverflow. Начните с изучения азов, а потом уже возвращайтесь с конкретными вопросами.

Comment: *...говорить процессу...* — это называется **Inter Process Communication (IPC)**. Ищите по этим ключевым словам.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight 24 вовсе нет